# Refresh only the component that changed from the parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that is a list, let's call it List, it has a state named items that is an array of object of the form :

```
{ id: String, name: String }
```

its render function is something like

```
render () {
    return (
        <ul>
          { items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

with Item being a react component too, of course.

So now, my question: let's say that at one point, I know that the data changed (it can only be a name change, of course), how can I trigger Item to refresh based on its key from the parent?

I found two solutions so far :

1. refreshing the whole state, but I don't like it cause it seems overkill.
2. maintaining an array of references to the child components, but I don't like it cause it feels like a waste of memory.

so what's a 'reactier' way of doing this?

Comment: [React docs tut on state / lifecycle management](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the items array changed then the render of the `Parent` is called, since the keys `Item` components are same, the component is not re-created but its `componentWillReceiveProps` function is called and the Item component is re-rendered.

What you can do as an optimization is to create a Item component as a Pure component which you can do by extending `React.PureComponent`. `React.PureComponent’s` `shouldComponentUpdate()` only shallowly compares the objects so if the Props haven't changed a rerender on child is not called.

> **According to the DOCS:**
>
> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result
>   given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a
>   performance boost in some cases.
>
> `React.PureComponent’s` `shouldComponentUpdate()` only shallowly
>   compares the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may
>   produce false-negatives for deeper differences. Only extend
>   `PureComponent` when you expect to have simple props and state, or use
>   `forceUpdate()` when you know deep data structures have changed. Or,
>   consider using immutable objects to facilitate fast comparisons of
>   nested data.
>
> Furthermore, `React.PureComponent’s` `shouldComponentUpdate()` skips
>   prop updates for the whole component subtree. Make sure all the
>   children components are also “pure”.

Answer (score 1):

By implementing [shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, newState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in your React components you can calculate whether or not the component needs to update. So if you send a whole new object in, this should trigger already in its default implementation (they don't do a deep-compare), but if the property `input.name` is changed then it will not detect this. So you could implement this yourself like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, newState) {
    return this.props.name === nextProps.name; // use === to compare types too!
}
```

Now I'm a bit rusty on the JavaScript (I prefer TypeScript), so I am not sure if this is the correct way to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using the shouldComponentUpdate() method, you can specify whether or not a component should update based on the current props and the new props which are provided as:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    return this.props.item.name !== nextProps.item.name; 
}
```

Here's a JsFiddle with a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Vorcan/Lakj6qwb/

Usually, you have to create a new object instance using something like [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Other than the docs, another good resource to check out shouldComponentUpdate is https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html